# Статический и динамический IP на роутере

Tags: сервер, ip, роутер

Дома есть Wi-Fi роутер, на нем динамический IP. Для того, чтобы 1 мой компьютер использовать как сервер, чтобы хостить на нем игровые сервера, доступные не только локально, а в мире - нужен статический IP. Сервер по майнкрафту же на локалхосте сам с собой играешь, и никто не может подключиться, вот и надобность статического IP. Возникает вопрос: как мне поступить, если на всех мобильных устройствах и 1 личном компьютере оставить динамический IP, а для компьютера в роли сервера для хостинга игровых проектов наладить статический IP?

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: `как мне поступить, если на всех мобильных устройствах и 1 личном компьютере оставить динамический IP, а для компьютера в роли сервера для хостинга игровых проектов наладить статический IP?`